# How to setup application for Remote Push Notifications like in Messenger

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification, uikit

I have problems with iOS application. I'm receiving push notification on this application but only when it is running (foreground/background with notification banner on top and sound).

When iOS is restarted for example and there is no application working in the background then I don't see any notification banner at all. What is wrong? I need to mention that I'm not interested in silent notifications which can wake up application. I'm interested in simple remote notifications without "content-available": 1 in json payload.
I'm trying to make it work in Development mode not Distribution.

Comparing to other applications like Messenger. Messenger don't have to be running in the background to receive notification banner in notification center on iOS. I'm trying to do it with iOS9.2. Does anybody have similar problems. I tried restarting my iPhone several times without luck. I read almost all apple developers guides related to Push Notifications.

Answer (score 0):

In Capabilities section of the Project enable the Background modes for Remote Notifications and enter the "Required Background Modes" in Info.plist file of project with appropriate requirement.

[image: Got]

And in the Info.plist of the project, do enter the "Required Background Modes" key with appropriate option suitable for your project.

[image]

Comment: Thank You for suggestion. The "Remote notifications" checkmark is set in my project and also it is visible in my application plist file under "Required Background Modes". I've set this yesterday but it's not working. I tried also restarting iPhone several times but problem is the same. When app is not running there is no push notification. When it is running in the background the notification is working ok.